How to start the PostgreSQL cluster using sudo systemctl while running as postgres user that has no password?
I am new to PostgreSQL world and I am facing this issue:
When I try to start postgres 14 cluster using the following command:
pg_ctlcluster 14 testcluster start

It starts but gives me the hint that:
Warning: the cluster will not be running as a systemd service. Consider using systemctl:
  sudo systemctl start postgresql@14-testcluster

And when I try the suggested command, it asks for unix user postgres password, which I have ever seen or set.
[sudo] password for postgres:


Note 1: Ubuntu 22.04

Note 2: I am running as postgres unix user using
this command:
sudo su - postgres



What can I do?

If you can do sudo su - postgres (apparently as some other user), you can also do sudo systemctl start (as that same user).

My main user is a sudoer, but appearantly postgres user is not. This error:
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
Also trying to run the cluster using the other sudoer user as sudo using this command:
sudo  systemctl start postgresql@14-testcluster
failed:
Job for postgresql@14-testcluster.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
but when I try:
sudo -u postgres systemctl start postgresql@14-testcluster
it asks for my sudoer password, which I don't have because I only use keys

As that same user (what you call "main").

"Job for postgresql@14-testcluster.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration"  OK, so figure out why. Look in the log file.

You can either edit /etc/sudoers to allow user postgres to run that command without having to specify a password, or you start and stop PostgreSQL using a different operating system user that has the permission to run the command.
